# TFS Build Server drop location error

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, network-share

We're using TFS Build Server to ensure that all files checked in by developers are going to compile to a working source tree, cuz there's nothing worse than a broken build!

Anyway we've having some problems with the drop location that Build Server wants to use, we keep getting this error:

> TFS209011: Could not create drop location \build-server\drops\project\BuildNumber. No more connections can be mades to this remote computer at this time because there are already as many connections as the computer can accept

Since this is being used in a pilot program at the moment we only have 2 projects which are using the Build Server. I've checked the network share and the allowed number of connections is about 100 so I don't really get what the problem is.

Only occationally does the problem raise it's head, quite often we'll not have one for days, and then we'll have a bunch in a row.

I can't seem to find much info on this either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is to do with our install of Windows 2003, we have "Web Edition" installed and it is limited to just 10 connections.

I ended up with a post of the MSDN forums in which I got this answer: http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3967598&SiteID=1&mode=1

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty good with TFS - but a dev not a network guy.  I would GUESS that while the NETWORK SHARE itself allows 100 connections, is it possible the underlying server it is running on doesn't have some sort of limitation?

Have you checked event logs?

This problem seems specific enough I would encourage you to post to the official Microsoft forums.